# How can I prevent the dialog on doing git commit --amend

Tags: git

There is a dialog that pops up on running:

```
git commit --amend
```

That wants me to review the messages.
Is there a way to omit this dialog and keep the same message as was provided last time?

Answer (score 6):

`--no-edit` is what you are looking for

```
git commit --amend --no-edit
```

From [this article](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/rewriting-git-history#!commit-amend):

> The editor will be populated with the message from the previous commit and including the --no-edit flag will allow you to make the ammendment to your commit without changing its commit message.

Answer (score 1):

Would `git commit --amend -C HEAD` work?

I don't have a git repository convenient to test on, but in the help for commit:

> -C , --reuse-message=<commit>
>
> Take an existing commit object, and reuse the log message and the 
>      authorship information (including the timestamp) when creating the commit.

Answer (score 0):

Just hit enter and then Ctrl+X to keep the same message

Comment: That's exactly what I wish I could avoid.

Comment: Come on, you only need to press 3 keys, what could be shorter?

Comment: It's in a batch file.